# Reading sensor data from serial device and publishing on MQTT

Tags: python, object-oriented, logging

I have a weather station with a [data logger](https://www.thiesclima.com/en/Products/Miscellaneous-Devices-Data-logger/?art=991) which accepts commands (specified in user manual) and sends back the respective data over a serial interface. In my case, I want to read the current data from the different sensors of the weather station in a specified interval and then publish them on a MQTT topic.

For this purpose I wrote a Python script with an object-oriented approach for better maintainability and to be able to extend some functionalities more easily, e.g. adding more functions for reading out some other data from the data logger.

This works fine for me now, but I wonder if my approach/structure is generally good so far or "if that's how you would do it" in a correct and tidy way.

**INFO** This script is running inside a docker container. As a daemon, unattended 24/7 operation is absolutely necessary. Maybe you have also tips on exception handling.

Overall I have one main file and files containing the different classes:

**main.py**

```
    import mqttClient
    import logger
    import watchdogResetter
    import dlxMetDatalogger
    
    from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
    import serial
    import os
    
    class WetterStationToMQTT:
        """Used to create all necessary functions and instances to get and publish weatherstation data
        """
        def __init__(self):
            os.environ['TZ']= 'Europe/Berlin' #set timezone for logger/watchdog
            self.logger = logger.Logger(os.environ['LOG_FILE_PATH'],os.environ['LOG_LEVEL_FILE'],os.environ['LOG_LEVEL_CONSOLE'])
            self.serialParameters = {
                'device'     : os.environ['SERIAL_DEVICE'], #specify in docker-compose.yaml
                'bytesize'   : serial.EIGHTBITS,
                'baud'       : 115200,
                'parity'     : serial.PARITY_NONE,
                'stopbit'    : serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                'timeout'    : 1
            }
            self.device = dlxMetDatalogger.DataloggerDLxMET_9_1756_x0_100(self.serialParameters)
            self.mqttServer = os.environ['MQTT_SERVER']      #specify in docker-compose.yaml
            self.mqttTopic = os.environ['MQTT_TOPIC']        #specify in docker-compose.yaml
            self.mqttClient = mqttClient.MQTTClient(self.mqttServer)
            self.watchdogResetter = watchdogResetter.WatchdogResetter(os.environ['WATCHDOG_FILE_PATH'])
            self.schedulerInterval_sec = int(os.environ['QUERY_INTERVAL_SEC']) #specify in docker-compose.yaml
    
            self.start()
    
        def schedulerjob_readDataAndPublish(self):
            """Scheduler worker function
            """
            try:
                currentDataMeasurement = self.device.measure_CurrentData()
                if(currentDataMeasurement.dataValid):
                    self.mqttClient.publishJson(self.mqttTopic, currentDataMeasurement.jsonData)
                    self.logger.logInfo("[o] Raw data: " + str(currentDataMeasurement.rawData))
                    self.logger.logInfo("[o] ParsedData: " + str(currentDataMeasurement.parsedData))
                else:
                    self.logger.logError("[x] Raw data: " + str(currentDataMeasurement.rawData))
                    self.logger.logError("[x] ParsedData: " + str(currentDataMeasurement.parsedData))
                self.watchdogResetter.resetWatchdog()
            except Exception as e:
                self.logger.logError(f"Exception {e} in scheduler worker function")
    
        def start(self):
            """Creates all necessary instances and starts scheduler.
            """
            try:
                self.scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
                self.scheduler.add_job(self.schedulerjob_readDataAndPublish, 'interval', seconds = self.schedulerInterval_sec)
                self.scheduler.start()
            except Exception as e:
                self.logger.logError(str(e))
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        wetterStationToMqtt = WetterStationToMQTT()
```

**mqttClient.py**

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
import json

class MQTTClient:  
    """A wrapper around the paho MQTT libary
    """     
    def __init__(self, mqttServer):
        """Establishes MQTT connection with given MQTT server.

        Args:
            mqttServer (String): Address of MQTT server (e.g. "172.23.62.255", "localhost", etc. )
        """
        self.mqttClient = mqtt.Client()
        self.mqttClient.connect(mqttServer, 1883)
        self.mqttClient.loop_start() # for keeping alive
            
    def publishJson(self, topic, jsonData):
        """Publishes data in the JSON format to the given topic

        Args:
            topic (String): The MQTT topic
            jsonData (String): JSON data
        """
        self.mqttClient.publish(topic, payload = jsonData)
```

**logger.py**

```
import logging
import os

class Logger:
    """Class providing logging functionalities
    """
    
    def __init__(self,logFilePath,loggerLevelFile,loggerLevelConsole):
        """Sets up a logger instance and handler to write the logs to a file and console
        """
        #set logs
        self.logger = logging.getLogger()
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO) 

        #formatting logs
        self.formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        
        # send logs to file
        self.filehandler = logging.FileHandler(logFilePath) 
        self.filehandler.setLevel(eval(f"logging.{loggerLevelFile}"))
        self.filehandler.setFormatter(self.formatter)
        self.logger.addHandler(self.filehandler)

        # send logs to console
        self.streamhandler = logging.StreamHandler()
        self.streamhandler.setLevel(eval(f"logging.{loggerLevelConsole}"))
        self.streamhandler.setFormatter(self.formatter)
        self.logger.addHandler(self.streamhandler)
        
    def logError(self,message):
        """Logs message with logger-level ERROR

        Args:
            message (string): Message to print with log
        """
        self.logger.error(message)
        
    def logWarning(self,message):
        """Logs message with logger-level WARNING

        Args:
            message (string): Message to print with log
        """
        self.logger.warning(message)
        
    def logInfo(self,message):
        """Logs message with logger-level INFO

        Args:
            message (string): Message to print with log
        """
        self.logger.info(message)
    
    def logDebug(self,message):
        """Logs message with logger-level DEBUG

        Args:
            message (string): Message to print with log
        """
        self.logger.debug(message)
```

**watchdogResetter.py**

```
from time import gmtime, strftime

class WatchdogResetter:
    """Used to reset the BCM2711 watchdog (on a raspberry pi 4)
    """
    def __init__(self,watchdogfilePath):
        """
        Args:
            watchdogfilePath (String): Path to the textfile checked by the watchdog module
        """
        self.watchdogfilePath=watchdogfilePath

    def resetWatchdog(self):
        """resets the watchdog by writing to the designated textfile monitored by the watchdog module
        """
        with open(self.watchdogfilePath, "w") as watchdogFile:
            watchdogFile.write(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())+"\n")
```

**dlxMetDatalogger.py**

```
import serial
import string
import measurement

BEGIN_OF_COMMAND = "\x02" #begin of command (ascii STX, see docu)
END_OF_COMMAND   = "\x03" #end of command (ascii ETX)

class DataloggerDLxMET_9_1756_x0_100:
    """Encapsulates one DLxMet 9.1756.x0.100 data logger (weather station)
    """
    def __init__(self,serialParameters):
        """Establishes serial connection with weather station
        """
        self.serialParameters = serialParameters
        #establish serial connection
        self.ser = serial.Serial(
            self.serialParameters['device'],
            self.serialParameters['baud'],
            self.serialParameters['bytesize'],
            self.serialParameters['parity'],
            self.serialParameters['stopbit'],
            self.serialParameters['timeout'])
        self.ser.flush()

    def ask(self, command_str):
        """Sends command to weather station and returns its answer

        Args:
            command_str (String): Command to send to the weather station (e.g. "mm" - for reading current sensordata)

        Returns:
            list: list of answer lines
        """
        #format command
        command_unicode = BEGIN_OF_COMMAND + command_str + END_OF_COMMAND
        command_bytes = bytearray(command_unicode, 'ascii')

        #send command
        self.ser.flush()
        self.ser.write(command_bytes)

        #read out data from datalogger
        rawData = []
        for line in self.ser.readlines(): 
            rawData.append(line)
        return rawData

    def measure_CurrentData(self):
        """Gets current sensor data

        Returns:
            DataloggerDLxMET_9_1756_x0_100_CurrentSensorData_Measurement: Measurement object
        """
        return measurement.DataloggerDLxMET_9_1756_x0_100_CurrentSensorData_Measurement(self,self.ask("mm"))
```

**measurement.py**

```
import re
import json

class DataloggerDLxMET_9_1756_x0_100_Measurement:
    """Encapsulates one (generic) measurement of the DLxMet 9.1756.x0.100 data logger (weather station)
    """
    def __init__(self,device,rawData):
        self.device=device
        self.rawData=rawData
        self.parsedData=None
        self.dataValid=False
        self.parseData()

    def parseData(self):
        raise NotImplementedError #Force subclass to implement method
    

class DataloggerDLxMET_9_1756_x0_100_CurrentSensorData_Measurement(DataloggerDLxMET_9_1756_x0_100_Measurement):
    """Encapsulates one current sensor values measurement of the DLxMet 9.1756.x0.100 data logger (weather station)
       (special case of DataloggerDLxMET_9_1756_x0_100_Measurement)
    """
    def __init__(self, device, rawData):
        super(DataloggerDLxMET_9_1756_x0_100_CurrentSensorData_Measurement,self).__init__(device,rawData)
        if(self.dataValid):
            self.convertDataToJSON()

    def parseData(self):
        """Parses self.rawData to self.parsedData (a dict). Sets self.dataValid if raw data could be parsed correctly
        """
        #regEx for strictly matching on correctly received data
        reString = ("(\d+\.\d+)\s+"         #hours and decimal minutes
                    "(\d+\.\d+)\s+"         #Windspeed
                    "(\d+)\s+"              #Winddirection
                    "([-]?\d+\.\d+)\s+"     #Temperature
                    "(\d+\.\d+)\s+"         #Humidity
                    "(\d+\.\d+)\s+"         #Precipitation
                    "(\d+\.\d+)\s+"         #Pressure
                    "(\d+\.\d+)\s+"         #Radiation
                    "(\?+\.\?+)\s+"         #not connected sensor => "???.?" in bytestring
                    "(\d+\.\d+)\s+"         #0.0
                    "(\d+\.\d+)\s+"         #1.0
                    "(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s+"    #Date
                    "(\d+\:\d+\:\d+)")      #Time
        matchedDataList = [item for sublist in re.findall(reString,str(self.rawData)) for item in sublist]

        #check data and convert sensordata to float
        self.dataValid = True
        if (len(matchedDataList) == 13 and matchedDataList[9] == '0.0' and matchedDataList[10] == '1.0'):
            for i in range(1,8):
                try:
                    matchedDataList[i] = float(matchedDataList[i])
                except ValueError:
                    self.dataValid = False
        else:
            self.dataValid = False
            return

        # write data into dict
        self.parsedData = {
                'windspeed' :     matchedDataList[1], 
                'winddirection' : matchedDataList[2], 
                'temperature' :   matchedDataList[3], 
                'humidity' :      matchedDataList[4], 
                'precipitation' : matchedDataList[5], 
                'pressure':       matchedDataList[6], 
                'radiation' :     matchedDataList[7]
            }
            
    def convertDataToJSON(self):
            """Converts self.parsedData to JSON string (self.jsonData)
            """
            self.jsonData = json.dumps(self.parsedData)
```

**For information:**

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '2'

services:
 wetterlog:
    build : .
    container_name: dataToMQTT
    restart: always
    volumes:
        - .:/code
        - ~/watchdog:/watchdog
        - ~/log:/log
    devices:
        - "/dev/ttyUSB0:/dev/ttyUSB0"
    ports:
        - 21883:1883
    environment:
        - SERIAL_DEVICE=/dev/ttyUSB0
        - MQTT_SERVER=172.23.62.107
        - MQTT_PORT=1883
        - MQTT_TOPIC=sensors
        - QUERY_INTERVAL_SEC=5
        - LOG_FILE_PATH=./log/log.txt
        - LOG_LEVEL_FILE=ERROR
        - LOG_LEVEL_CONSOLE=INFO
        - WATCHDOG_FILE_PATH=./watchdog/watchdog.txt
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:alpine3.7
WORKDIR /
COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /
CMD python __main__.py
```